# Efficient way of find neighbours of coordinates, dependent on direction - Matlab

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

I would like to find the 4 nearest neighbours for a dataset roughly 2000 X,Y coordinates in X and Y direction with varying distance between the points along the Y axis and along the X-axis. For example: `distance along x-axis = 5, distance along y-axis=3`

The picture belows shows examplary what I am trying to achieve for a single point. Points at the end/ edges of the data set would correspondingly have 3 (in corners - 2) neighbours.

[image]

BML is a matrix 2000 x3 (X in column 2, Y in column 3), x/y_blockdimension is the distance between points.

```
for NB=1:length(BML);
NB_list=zeros(4,1);
%in +x direction
if isempty(find(BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2)+x_blockdimension & BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3), 1));
    NB_list(1,1)=0;
else
    NB_list(1,1)=find(BML(:,2)==(BML(NB,2)+x_blockdimension)& BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3));

end
%in - x direction
 if isempty(find(BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2)-x_blockdimension & BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3), 1));
    NB_list(2,1)=0;
else
    NB_list(2,1)=find(BML(:,2)==(BML(NB,2)-x_blockdimension)& BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3));

 end

 %in +y direction
 if isempty(find(BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3)+y_blockdimension & BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2), 1));
    NB_list(3,1)=0;
else
    NB_list(3,1)=find(BML(:,3)==(BML(NB,3)+y_blockdimension)& BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2));

 end
%in -y direction
 if isempty(find(BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3)-y_blockdimension & BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2), 1));
    NB_list(4,1)=0;
else
    NB_list(4,1)=find(BML(:,3)==(BML(NB,3)-y_blockdimension)& BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2));

end

NB_list_all(NB,:)=NB_list;
end
```

The above code works perfectly fine by now, but I am wondering whether there is a shorter more efficient way of finding the neighbours?

Comment: General debugging advice:I'd recommend taking a smaller matrix to test on, putting in a breakpoint and pulling apart the statement into smaller parts to find exactly which term is causing the error.

Comment: I would guess that checking for equality with floats could be a factor `BM(:,2)==BM(NB,2)+x_blockdimension`, or maybe that you have `BM(NB,3)` in the `isempty` line and `BM(NB,3)` two lines below?

Comment: Actually I suspect you're trying to assign a vector `find(...)` to a single value `NB_list(1,1)`

Comment: in last row of code it was supposed to be ==BM(NB,3)) ... but it still gives the same error ...

Comment: do you know if there is a better idea to find the sorrounding coordinates ?

Comment: If you can put them in a logical order so the surrounding points for `A(ii,jj)` are `[A(ii+1,jj), A(ii-1,jj), A(ii,jj+1), A(ii,jj-1)]` that's generally a good idea. If it's stored in a vector they might be `[A(ii+1), A(ii-1), A(ii+N), A(ii-N)]` where `N` is the length of a column (or row if stored row-wise).You have to be careful at the edges. If they're unordered, I'm not sure.